# PHP функция imagecopy всегда право низ

Tags: php

По умолчанию для функции imagecopy расположение логотипа, лево-верх.

```
imagecopy (resource dst_im, resource src_im, int dst_x, int dst_y, int src_x, int src_y, int src_w, int src_h)
```

Как можно сделать чтобы для изображений любых размеров, накладывалось всегда право-низ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно узнать размеры обоих изображений. Соответственно

```
list($iw1, $ih1) = getimagesize($logo_path);
list($iw2, $ih2) = getimagesize($path);
imagecopy($desct, $source, $iw2 - $iw1, $ih2 - $ih1, 0, 0, $iw1, $ih1);
// могу попутать порядок 3,4 и 5,6 аргументов
```

Answer (score 0):

ну так а в чем проблема узнавать размеры конечного изображения и отступать нужное количество пикселей сверху и слева?